# Append to CloudBlockBlob stream

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have a file system abstraction that allows us to easily switch between local and cloud (Azure) storage.

For reading and writing files we have the following members:

```
Stream OpenRead();
Stream OpenWrite();
```

Part of our application "bundles" documents into one file. For our local storage provider `OpenWrite` returns an *appendable* stream:

```
public Stream OpenWrite()
{
    return new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, BufferSize, useAsync: true);
}
```

For Azure blob storage we do the following:

```
public Stream OpenWrite()
{               
    return blob.OpenWrite();
}
```

Unfortunately this overrides the blob contents each time. Is it possible to return a writable stream that can be appended to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the documentation for `OpenWrite` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.openwrite.aspx, `The OpenWrite method will overwrite an existing blob unless explicitly prevented using the accessCondition parameter.`

One thing you could do is read the blob data in a stream and return that stream to your calling application and let that application append data to that stream. For example, see the code below:

```
    static void BlobStreamTest()
    {
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        CloudBlobContainer container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("temp");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.txt");
        blob.UploadFromStream(new MemoryStream());//Let's just create an empty blob for the sake of demonstration.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    blob.DownloadToStream(ms);//Read blob data in a stream.
                    byte[] dataToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is line # " + (i + 1) + "\r\n");
                    ms.Write(dataToWrite, 0, dataToWrite.Length);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    blob.UploadFromStream(ms);
                }
            }
            catch (StorageException excep)
            {
                if (excep.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode != 404)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The recommended approach seems to be `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlock` but we're relying on a PDF library to perform our "bundling" which will only work with a single input stream.

Comment: `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlock` is recommended because if the file becomes large, then the approach above would not be efficient as you're download entire blob and uploading it again. With `PutBlock` you're only uploading the appended part.

Comment: Yes this is a big downside of *replacing* the blob each time. However, as mentioned, we're limited by our PDF library. We may look at caching a local copy of the blob if this becomes a problem.

Comment: Link to MSDN is broken due to Microsoft structure change

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [`CloudAppendBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudappendblob?view=azure-dotnet) class that allows you to add content to an existing blob :

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage account connectionstring");
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("container name");
var blob = container.GetAppendBlobReference("blob name");
```

In your case you want to append from a stream:

```
await blob.AppendFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream());
```

But you can append from text, byte array, file. Check the documentation.