# How to set blob properties in an Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

[This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata#set-and-retrieve-properties) shows how to set blob properties such as `ContentType` using C#. How can this be done in the following Azure Function? The method signature does not use a `CloudBlob` object, but rather a `Stream` object to read the blob.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("container-name/folder-name/{name}", Connection = "ConnectionString")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, Binder binder)
{
    // How to change the ContentType property?
}
```

Comment: `Inheritance Stream -> CloudBlobStream` That's just working with it in memory. Convert it to a `cloudBlobStream`

Comment: Could you provide an answer with a working example? I changed the method signature, but there was no "Properties" field on the object.

Comment: Don't change the method signature. Keep it as a stream and append it to a cloudblob object. Try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161869/append-to-cloudblockblob-stream I can't really put it in an answer to test because I don't have an environment for that.

Comment: There is no CloudBlobStream in the link that you provided?

Comment: That link shows an example of using `cloudblob` with `stream`. It should be what you're looking for. Convert the `stream` into a `memorystream`, then read that into a `cloudblob` object.

Comment: Seems similar to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810745/azure-function-with-blobtrigger-update-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the code below(I'm using visual studio 2017, and create function v2):

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("container-name/folder-name/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]ICloudBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("...change blob property...");

            //specify the property here
            myBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/html";

            //commit the property
            myBlob.SetPropertiesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```